# Авторизация в samba на linux Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

Не удаётся на удалённой машине авторизоваться с именем hb1c.
Сервер на ubuntu 16.04 server

```
cat /etc/samba/smb.conf | grep -v '#'


[global]


   workgroup = WORKGROUP

    server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)


;   wins server = w.x.y.z

   dns proxy = no


;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

;   bind interfaces only = yes




   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

   max log size = 1000


   syslog = 0

   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d



   server role = standalone server

   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

   unix password sync = yes

   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

   pam password change = yes

   map to guest = bad user



;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U

;   logon drive = H:

;   logon script = logon.cmd

; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g


;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash


;   usershare max shares = 100

   usershare allow guests = yes


;[homes]
;   comment = Home Directories
;   browseable = no

;   read only = yes

;   create mask = 0700

;   directory mask = 0700

;   valid users = %S

;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[hb1c-base]
path = /home/hb1c/1cbase
browseble = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
valid users = hb1c
create mask = 0750
directory mask = 0750
```

Статус:

```
watch smbstatus
smbstatus only works as root!

samba -V
Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/samba

Теперь надо разобраться с пользователями.
Samba использует пользователей которые уже есть в системе, возьмем для примера имя user, допустим что он уже есть в системе, надо внести его в базу данных SMB и назначить пароль для доступа к общим ресурсам, сделаем это командой:

```
smbpasswd -a user
```

Вам будет предложено ввести пароль, пользователь будет добавлен в базу, теперь необходимо включить этого пользователя.

```
smbpasswd -e user
```

Далее создадим псевдоним для имени пользователя user что бы облегчить себе доступ с Windows машины на которой у нас например пользователь с именем Admin, для этого создадим и отредактируем файл /etc/samba/smbusers:

```
sudo touch /etc/samba/smbusers
sudo gedit /etc/samba/smbusers
```

Впишите в файл пару строк

```
# Unix_name = SMB_name1 SMB_name2
user = Admin
```

На этом настройка закончена, перезапустите Samba.